# Overriding Core Login controller in Concrete5.6.2

Tags: php, authentication, controller, concrete5

I want to overriding core login controller in Concrete5 latest version without editing core files. because i want to add extra functionlity in do_login method of login controller. I have tried. But it doesnt work. 
I have copied
concrete/core/controllers/singlepages/login.php to controllers/login.php and I have added a line in controllers/login.php as follows

```
defined('C5_EXECUTE') or die("Access Denied.");
Loader::library('authentication/open_id');
class LoginController extends Concrete5_Controller_Login { 
}

class Concrete5_Controller_Login extends Controller { 
....
.....
}
```

Comment: You haven't actually stated what your problem is?

Comment: Check if your override is loaded by putting `die();` in the beginning. if not, check if you've deactivated the override chache.

Comment: The second class decleration in your example doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You should only be overriding the Concrete5_Controller_Login, not the base Controller class.

```
defined('C5_EXECUTE') or die("Access Denied.");
Loader::library('authentication/open_id');
class LoginController extends Concrete5_Controller_Login { 
....
.....
}
```

So move your functioning code from the 2nd class into the 1st class, then remove the 2nd class declaration from the file.